# CentOS 7's vim can't open help (when run as root) because it can't handle the gzipped help files

Tags: linux, vim

I found a strange issue with vim that I can't seem to easily fix:

```
[root@localhost .vim]# vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jun 10 2014 06:55:55)
Included patches: 1-160
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
```

Just doing some messing around as root user on a VM here... I installed `vim` with `yum`, it works great with my config files... the only thing is I can't read most of the Vim documentation.

[image]

I even tried adding this to `.vimrc`:

```
augroup gzip
 autocmd!
 autocmd BufReadPre,FileReadPre *.gz set bin
 autocmd BufReadPost,FileReadPost   *.gz '[,']!gunzip
 autocmd BufReadPost,FileReadPost   *.gz set nobin
 autocmd BufReadPost,FileReadPost   *.gz execute ":doautocmd BufReadPost " . expand("%:r")
 autocmd BufWritePost,FileWritePost *.gz !mv <afile> <afile>:r
 autocmd BufWritePost,FileWritePost *.gz !gzip <afile>:r
 autocmd FileAppendPre      *.gz !gunzip <afile>
 autocmd FileAppendPre      *.gz !mv <afile>:r <afile>
 autocmd FileAppendPost     *.gz !mv <afile> <afile>:r
 autocmd FileAppendPost     *.gz !gzip <afile>:r
augroup END
```

It did not fix it or even change the behavior, my thinking is that these autocmds are already set by default to begin with.

Has this happened to anyone? I'm even running this as root user so i don't really understand why some particular `options.txt.gz` file would even be read-only.

Now I do have to admit that everything seems to work fine if I actually log in to my own user account instead of root. So I guess this can still serve as a pretty good reminder to not do everything as root user...

Comment: Why do you have those files gzipped in the first place?

Comment: I didn't touch them. This is just how it is. I just installed vim, `yum install vim`

Comment: Well, those files are not supposed to be gzipped. Find out why they are… maybe the package you have installed is at fault? Can you tell us where those files are located?

Comment: `"/usr/share/vim/vim74/doc/options.txt.gz" [readonly] 425 lines`  And accessed from my non root user: `"/usr/share/vim/vim74/doc/options.txt.gz" [readonly] 8297 lines`. This looks like its saying that it's dynamically ungzipping it for me (properly)

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the faq [Can I use compressed versions of the help files?](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-4.6)

BTW: Is helpgrep working on CentOS? If not, you might want to consider opening a bug report at Cent OS and request not to compress the help files.