# can't open vim helpfile because error E21

Tags: vim

when I try to open vim helptext (i.e. :h fold), vim failed to open it with E21 error: can't make change modifiable is off. 
How can I fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Does this still happen if you open vim with `vim -u NONE`?

Comment: I tried your suggestion. E21 error goes away. But with a new error E434: can't find tag pattern. And the helptext is incorrectly displayed, looks like an encoding issue. Any idea? --thanks.

Comment: Maybe this answer will help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107149/trouble-getting-help-in-vim

Comment: i found a similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026230/centos-7s-vim-cant-open-help-when-run-as-root-because-it-cant-handle-the-gz

Comment: It looks like an issue withe centos vim package. My solution is to unzip those helptext files manually.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out to be an issue with centos vim package.

My solution is to unzip those helptext files manually and change the tags files to use .txt instead of .gz.